# Best way of setting a maximum connection timeout in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, connection-timeout

I know you can set the Connection Timeout parameter on the ConnectionString, however, it sets the minimum timeout time and not the maximum.

My application works connected to a remote database and it needs to gray out the screen and wait for the connection to come back if it had been lost. I already do this fine, but sometimes when the connection is lost it takes more than 30 seconds to it realize the connection is lost, even with a minimum Connetion Timeout parameter value.

I detect the connection is lost because I have a thread doing a polling on the database every 0.5 second, and I wait for it to throw the "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" exception.

I want to know if there is a nice way of setting a maximum timeout or other alternative to it detect faster that the connection is lost.

**Edit:** I didn't know that also existed the *CommandTimeout*. It doesn't work perfectly but works better. It have to be set on every new DataContext object but it's fine. I set to a value X and it seems to always take X + 5 seconds to throw a Timeout exception.

Comment: What do you mean for maximum connection timeout and what is the difference with the minimum connection timeout?

Comment: @Steve When I set it to 5, for example, it means it will not timeout _before_ 5 seconds, that's what I mean by being minimum, and it's the way it works... it will throw the excpetion on an arbitrary time after 5 seconds. A maximum timeout would mean that it would throw the excpetion on the exact moment it surpassed 5 seconds of waiting.

Comment: hm can it maybe confuse things that your server polling interval is much smaller than your timeout? I think it should be the other way around. Do you open a new connection each time you poll? Or is the polling independent from the connection itself? Did you try to reproduce this locally without a remote server? Because the sql connection "randomly" terminating at "some time" after the timeout-interval does not seem right imho.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Well, inside the polling thread it have a method that makes a query, so it doesn't matter the polling interval as it will be locked in this method until the exception is thrown or it succeds.

Comment: hmmm, but still it seems like a waste to poll in shorter intervals than a query might finish in its worst case. (if you don't do anything else during that polling)

Comment: ConnectionTimeout is the timeout to connect to the server. CommandTimeout is the timeout for a command to return. People often assume that the commandTimeout is by default the same as the connectionTimeout but it isn't. Setting the connectionTimeout has no effect on the commandTimout, you have to set it every time.

Comment: @Ben so assuming one would have `One connection per command`, the smaller value of both "wins"?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, no, the connectiontimeout is the timeout for the connection `Open()` call. It doesn't apply to commands at all. The CommandTimeout applies to the `Execute` or `ExecuteScalar` calls. It doesn't apply to connections at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I found was to create another class to detect when the connection was lost.

This class would create 2 threads, one that calls a method to check if the database exists and then set a flag to true; and another that would check if the flag was true after a certain amount of time. If it was still false after the certain amount of time, it means that the database connection was lost and the first thread is locked waiting for the timeout. This way I don't need to wait for the timeout to happen to detect it.

Answer (score 3):

the `ConnectionTimeout` is the timeout for the connection `Open()` call. It doesn't apply to commands at all. The `CommandTimeout` applies to the `Execute` or `ExecuteScalar` calls. It doesn't apply to connections at all.

To apply the `CommandTimeout` to all commands you have to do it every time you create a Command object.